# sql how to show increment as fraction of total increment

Tags: sql, database, presto

Suppose that I have the following sql data

```
species         date         observations
Bird1           08-09-19          40
Bird1           06-10-19          50
Bird1           11-11-19          60
Bird2           08-09-19          50
Bird2           06-10-19          90
Bird3           06-10-19          10
Bird3           11-11-19          20
```

and suppose that I want to show for a month and a bird species, what the incremental change in observations was (with respect to the previous month), as a fraction of the total increment of observations of bird species for that month. Given the example data, I would want the following result.

```
species         date         observations      increment_fraction
Bird1           08-09-19          40                    0
Bird1           06-10-19          50                    0.2
Bird1           11-11-19          60                    0.5
Bird2           08-09-19          50                    0
Bird2           06-10-19          90                    0.8
Bird3           06-10-19          10                    0
Bird3           11-11-19          20                    0.5
```

Let me explain these results. The increment fractions corresponding to the date `08-09-19` is 0 because there are no earlier records available. The second row has an increment fraction of 0.2, because the **total increment** in observations between the date `08-09-19` and `06-10-19` is 50, and the increment change for **Bird1** between `08-09-19` and `06-10-19` is 10. Increment fraction is 10/50 = 0.2.

The same goes for the third row: the **total increment** between dates `06-10-19` and `11-11-19` is 20, and the increment for **Bird1** between dates `06-10-19` and `11-11-19` is 10. Increment fraction is 10/20 = 0.5.

The following query will give me the desired result:

```
with increments_table as (
select species, date, observations, 
observations - lag(observations, 1, observations) over (partition by species 
order by date) as increment
from species_table),

increment_sums as (
select date, sum(increment) as increment_sum
from increments_table
group by date)

select species, date, observations, increment/increment_sum
from increments_table
join increment_sums
on increments_table.date = increment_sums.date
```

But I was wondering whether this could be a bit more compact. I think it can be more compact as it is quite a basic operation, but I'm not sure how.

**Question:** Is there a way to do this shorter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the base you used to calculate increment is always the first available data point, in that case, the 1-step solution will be:

```
select species, date, observations, 
(observations / first_value(observations) over (partition by species order by date)) - 1 as increment_fraction
from species_table
```

Of course if your `observations` column is an integer, than you might need to cast that to a `float/double` so that you can get the decimal fraction values.